# Mean and Standard Deviation self thought problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I am 13 years old trying to teach myself about standard deviation and was wondering how this problem would look like. I know I am young to be learning this but I was reading about this and got interested. I understand it a little but I wanted to see more of a solution to this problem. I have an idea of what the deviation is like, but I would like to see the written out solution.

> In a certain school, the heights of the population of girls are normally distributed, with a mean of $63$ inches and a standard deviation of 2 inches. If there are $450$ girls in the school, determine how many of the girls are shorter than 60 inches. Round the answer to the nearest integer.

Comment: So what's your idea? Do you know what normally distributed means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a calculator, there's no way to do this by hand. If the standard deviation is $\sigma = 2$ inches, and you want to know how many girls are shorter than $60$ inches, then since the mean is $63$ inches, then since $63-60 = 3$, then you want to know how many girls are at most $-1.5$ standard deviations below the mean. So you need to use a calculator (or look it up in a table) that tells you what proportion corresponds to $<-1.5 \sigma$. For example, you may use [this website](http://www.vassarstats.net/zp.html?).

If you use that website and put in $z = -1.5$ and click "calculate", it tells you that the "one-tailed" probability for $z$ is $0.0668$. This means that the probability that somebody is less than $-1.5$ times the standard deviation below the mean is $0.0668$. Then you multiply this probability by the total number of girls, so you get

$$ 450 \times 0.0668 = 30.06 \approx 30$$

Comment: Technically, you can do this by hand. It would require taking the normal distribution (which is only described by a somewhat messy integral) and then evaluating it using some approximation, likely trapezoid rule. Though for the purposes of this question, you do NOT want to do this by hand. It is entirely reasonable as well to look up such things because no one actually recalculates them.

Comment: Thank you Christopher. I see how it works now